# Display loader while waiting for data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have simple php based website, which queries other websites for some data.
I need to show some loading image, while processing the data.

I tried following, but the loader shows just for a moment, once the page is loaded and fades out.

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

css

```
#loading {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: url('img/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

To better explain what happens and what I need, say the load time of a page is 10 seconds. Now page loads for 10 seconds, not showing loader and after 10 seconds it shows loader fading it out.
I'd need to show loader for full 10 seconds and then fade it out.

Comment: What's the CSS for `#loading`?

Comment: I guess the problem could be that the background image doesn't get loaded in time, but I'm not sure. Try to encode your image as a base64 data URI and see what it gives. http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/  You an also just put a red background and see if you see the element. If not then your problem is elsewhere... are you hiding the `#loading` element somewhere initially?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your page won't even start loading until PHP sends a response. And it will send a response only after 10 seconds with all queries done. What you should do is to have a static page that first loads itself (quick) and then calls your PHP script separately via AJAX. You can show the loader during that call.

You can also try switching off PHP output buffering and sending (echoing) part of the page containing the loader before you do any slow queries.